# Angular ocLazyLoad not load for second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

I'm using ocLazyLoad and initialize it at ui-router resolve:

```
$stateProvider
   .state('user', {
       url: '/user',
       resolve: {
       loader: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/user/user.app.js');
           }]
       }
    })
   .state('admin', {
       url: '/admin',
       resolve: {
       loader: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/admin.app.js');
           }]
       }
    })
```

The problem is when I first reload the page (to `/admin`), it works perfectly. But if i go to `/user` (still load) and back again to `/admin` the JS won't load. and still using `/user`js.

I've tried add `cache:false` for every route stil not working.

Any solution?

Comment: i use $ocLazyLoad who work perfectly but i dont use $stateProvider but $routeProvider

Comment: oh my project already using $stateProvider. it's take too many time to change it to $routeprovider. and i read at oclazyload docs, it says working with $stateprovider. even their example using $stateprovider

Comment: of course. in my app it load only one time the js file and keep them in memory

Comment: I think that's the whole point of ocLazyLoad is just to load it only when it's needed and load it only once, there must be something else wrong with the code